# Differential geometry related question

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

This question is a follow-up to a question posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314660/find-the-parametric-equation-of-the-curve-to-be-the-intersection-of-the-parabolo)

After tweaking the parametrization a little bit, I decided to go with this:
$$x=\frac{1}{2}\cos(t) , y=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sin(t) , z=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sin(t)$$
Without doing arc length parametrization( trying to do so I got $s=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}\left | sin(\tau) \right |d\tau$, which I didn't know how to solve), I tried doing it the other way round. I found that :
$$\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}=(-\frac{1}{2}\sin(t), \frac{1}{2}\cos(t),\frac{1}{2}\cos(t))$$
The binormal vector is now given by $$\vec{B}=\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}\times \frac{d^{2}\vec{r}}{dt}$$
and the normal vector is simply $$\vec{N}=\vec{B}\times \vec{T}$$
The equations for them become very nasty expressions, so I am very relcutant to type them out. There's two things that are unclear to me now:

1. If I wanted to compute the curvature, $\kappa $, at some point which formula do I use? By definition  we have that $\kappa =\left | \frac{d^{2}\vec{r}}{ds} \right | $ which is in terms of the natural parameter. How can I use my non-parametrized equations to obtain the curvature?

2.By computation I got that $$\vec{B}=\left ( 0,\frac{\cos^{2}t}{4}- \frac{\sin^{2}t}{4}, -\frac{\cos^{2}t}{4}+\frac{\sin^{2}t}{4}\right )$$
Can't I just write it as  $\vec{B}=\left (  0,1,-1\right )$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your curve lies in the plane $y = z$ (and in fact is an ellipse whose major axis is $\sqrt{2}$ times the minor axis, since $y = x^{2} + y^{2}$ defines a right circular cylinder with axis parallel to the $z$-axis), its binormal vector is indeed constant. In your cross product formula, you need to normalize. So $B = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(0, 1, -1)$ up to an overall sign. This should make your curvature expression a lot nicer. :)

(Separately, because your curve is an ellipse, it would be hopeless to seek an explicit arc length parametrization....)

Comment: Hi, I am having some trouble finding the curvature. Do I use the formula $\kappa =\frac{\left \| \vec{r}^{'}\times \vec{r}^{''} \right \|}{\left \| \vec{r} \right \|^{3}}$

Comment: Yes, that should be straightforward. (The prime seems to be missing in the denominator, but that may be my browser's rendering....)

Comment: It should be there, but it isn't.